# Regarding the differences in the styles displayed in different browsers

Tags: html, css, web, cross-browser, display

I found that the line I drew is displayed differently in the two browsers, which is very strange. Does it seem that its margin has changed?

Here is displayed in Google Chrome:
[image]

And here is displayed in Firefox:
[image]

Here is my css code for drawing the line:

```
.line {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    margin: 30px 0;
}

.inputContainer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin-top: -20px;
}

.inputContainer #loginForm {
    margin-top: -250px;
}

.inputContainer h2 {
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.inputContainer p {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 15px 0;
}
```

Here is my section html code:

```
<div class="buttonList">
        <div class="buttonListE"><button id="ad_A">Cloud Music Free</button></div>
        <div class="buttonListE"><button id="ad_B">The Best Music Webapp</button></div>
        <div class="buttonListE"><button id="ad_C">Enjoy this moment</button></div>
    </div>
    <div class="inputContainer">
        <form action="register.php" id="loginForm" method="POST">
            <div class="line"></div>
            <h2>To continue, log in to Cloud Music</h2>
            <p>
                <label for="loginUsername">Email address or username</label>
                <input type="text" id="loginUsername" name="loginUsername" placeholder="Email address or username." value="<?php keepValueLastTime('loginUsername'); ?>" required>
                <?php echo $account->getError(Constants::$loginFailedUsername); ?>
                <?php echo $account->getError(Constants::$loginFailedEmail); ?>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="loginPassword">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="loginPassword" name="loginPassword" placeholder="Password." required>
            </p>
            <button class="greenButton" type="submit" name="loginButton">LOG IN</button>
            <div></div>
            <div class="hasAccountText">
                <div class="line"></div>
                <span>Don't have an account?</span>
                <button class="greyButton"  id="hideLogin" type="button">SIGN UP HERE</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Can you post a code snippet with your HTML and CSS?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have posted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox appears to have issues with negative `margin` in some instances. I noticed that you gave the form `margin-top: -250px` when putting it in a flex-container that had `align-items: center` which seems counter-intuitive. Try using this method:

```css
.line {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.inputContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin-top: -20px;
}

.inputContainer h2 {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.inputContainer p {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 15px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttonList">
  <div class="buttonListE"><button id="ad_A">Cloud Music Free</button></div>
  <div class="buttonListE"><button id="ad_B">The Best Music Webapp</button></div>
  <div class="buttonListE"><button id="ad_C">Enjoy this moment</button></div>
</div>
<div class="inputContainer">
  <form action="register.php" id="loginForm" method="POST">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <h2>To continue, log in to Cloud Music</h2>
    <p>
      <label for="loginUsername">Email address or username</label>
      <input type="text" id="loginUsername" name="loginUsername" placeholder="Email address or username." value="<?php keepValueLastTime('loginUsername'); ?>" required>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="loginPassword">Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="loginPassword" name="loginPassword" placeholder="Password." required>
    </p>
    <button class="greenButton" type="submit" name="loginButton">LOG IN</button>
    <div></div>
    <div class="hasAccountText">
      <div class="line"></div>
      <span>Don't have an account?</span>
      <button class="greyButton" id="hideLogin" type="button">SIGN UP HERE</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

An alternative could be this instead of `margin-top: -250px`

```css
position: relative;
top: -250px;
```

This `top` property seems to work for some as well so be sure to give this a try.